# reference count never decrease to zero Py_DECREF

Tags: python, c++

When I run the following code, the while circulation never stops. Why?

### Will the PyObject pointer change to Null when the reference number is zero?

```
#include <sched.h>
#include <Python.h>
int main() {
    Py_Initialize(); 
    PyObject *pModule;
    int time=0;
    pModule = PyImport_ImportModule("entry"); 
    while(pModule!=NULL)
    {
        Py_DECREF(pModule);
        time++;
        printf("this is  decref pmodule, times= %d",time);
    }
    Py_Finalize();  
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

When the reference count reaches zero, the object pointed to is destroyed, and the memory is released.

This does not affect your pointer in any way, but you're left with an invalid pointer to the released memory.

This is exactly the same as "normal" C++; `delete p` does not affect the value of `p`, only that of `*p` and the pointer's validity.